# Gorm left join with Scan()

Tags: go, join, left-join, go-gorm

I am trying to join to tables `Class` and `Booking` on `classes.id = bookings.class_id` and get the result of the type `DisplayBooking`

```
type Class struct {
    Id   int    `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

type Booking struct {
    Id      int    `json:"id"`
    User    string `json:"user"`
    Members int    `json:"members"`
    ClassId int    `json:classid`
    //Class   Class  `gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:SET NULL;"`
}
type DisplayBooking struct {
    Id        int    `json:"id"`
    User      string `json:"user"`
    Members   int    `json:"members"`
    ClassId   int    `json:classid`
    ClassName string `json:"classname"`
}
```

To do that I tried gorm's `Scan()` and `Rows()` methods

```
func returnAllBookings(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    bookings := []DisplayBooking{}

    db.Model(&Booking{}).Select("bookings.id, bookings.user, bookings.members, bookings.class_id, classes.name").Joins("left join classes on bookings.class_id = classes.id").Scan(&bookings)

    fmt.Println("Endpoint Hit: returnAllBookings")

    rows, err := db.Table("bookings").Select("bookings.id, bookings.user, bookings.members, bookings.class_id, classes.name").Joins("left join classes on bookings.class_id = classes.id").Rows()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    for rows.Next() {
        log.Println(rows)
    }
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(bookings)
}
```

`Scan()` return null values in class_name field, and while `Rows()` seems to do the job the output format is not a JSON encoding
`Scan()` output

```
[{"id":1,"user":"test1","members":1,"ClassId":2,"classname":""},{"id":2,"user":"test2","members":2,"ClassId":1,"classname":""}]
```

`Rows()` output (console) - bold values are correct, but there's a lot of unnecessary information

```
my-go-app_1  | 2021/04/09 07:42:09 &{0xc00021e1b0 0x6dcfa0 0xc00026adc0 <nil> <nil> {{0 0} 0 0 0 0} false <nil> **[1 test1 1 2 business]**}
my-go-app_1  | 2021/04/09 07:42:09 &{0xc00021e1b0 0x6dcfa0 0xc00026adc0 <nil> <nil> {{0 0} 0 0 0 0} false <nil> **[2 test2 2 1 first]**}
```

Is there a way to make the code work with `Scan()` function?

Comment: what is the use of scan? what does it do or what benefits does it provide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `Scan`, there's no value in `class_name` field of `DisplayBooking` is because the default `gorm tag name` of the field is `class_name`, but the column you want to match is `name`, those two are mismatched.

You can add a column alias name to fix this problem, change your `Scan()` expression to the following one:

```
db.Debug().Model(&Booking{}).Select("bookings.id, bookings.user, bookings.members, bookings.class_id, classes.name as class_name").Joins("left join classes on bookings.class_id = classes.id").Scan(&bookings)
```

Comment: how do we get elements of the row? like `rows.User`? or rows["users"]?